# insert jdatechooser from java to database

Tags: java

How can I insert jdatechooser from java to database? I have used all the solutions of the net but still I can't insert. Please help me.
I'm using eclipse environment. 
This is my code:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement stm= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO d"+
            "(dateEntré)"+
            "VALUES(?)");

    ((PreparedStatement)stm).setDate(1,convertUtilDateToSqlDate(dateChooser.getDate()));
    statement.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"added");
} catch (Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is an exception thrown? If so, please post the stack trace. And why the two statements (`statement` and `stm`)? And why `executeQuery` on an INSERT?

Comment: Is the column type in the database compatible with java.sql.Date?

Comment: What's "`stmt`"? You're using `statement` when you prepare the statement and execute the query, but you're binding the value to `stmt`?

Comment: i was wrong instead of  stm i put statement

Comment: could you correct me this code

Comment: @Med Ka, please edit your code with the current code you are using. And please elaborate on the problem (answer questions in first comment above)

Comment: try {
     PreparedStatement stm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO d"+
                            "(dateEntré)"+
                                     "VALUES(?)");

     ((PreparedStatement) stm).setDate(1,convertUtilDateToSqlDate(dateChooser.getDate()));
     stm.execute();
        
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"added");

  
    } catch (Exception e1) {

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1.getMessage());


    }
    
   }

Comment: i could not sent the date*, selected by the user from a JDateChooser, into a database table.

Comment: Why are you casting? If you use `java.sql.PreparedStatement` (like you should), there should be no need for casting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example seems to be wrong, and this could just be a typo, but since you've provided no other information with regards to the error, this is all we have to go on...

You create a `PreapredStatement` called `stmt`, but then use `statement` to `execute` the query.

You should be using the same variable/instance to bind and excute the query.  You should probably also use `executeUpdate` instead of `execute`, this provides some additional information when the statement is executed about the number of rows that were affected by the update.

```
try {
    PreparedStatement stm= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO d (dateEntré) VALUES(?)");

    stm.setDate(1,convertUtilDateToSqlDate(dateChooser.getDate()));
    int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
    if (rows > 0) { // Should be 1
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"added");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update failed for unknown reason");
    }
} catch (Exception e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1.getMessage());
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This of course assumes that the database column is a compatible type of `java.sql.Date`

Take a closer look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot MadProgrammer it's ok but I want to ask a question what does it mean row>0 and thanks again :)

Comment: `executeUpdate` returns the number of rows that were updated, in your case it should be `1`, so we check to see if the `row` value is greater then `0`

Comment: hanks for the answer  and please how can i change the format of datechooser to dd-mm-yyyy this date to